# HTTPS headers showing cleartext passwords

Tags: ssl, https, openssl

I have just set up a SelfSigned Open SSL certificate on my server. I am monitoring the network traffic in Chrome' network inspector. Under the Form Data header I can see all of the information in cleartext, is this normal? I would think it would be encrypted. I have a very basic form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="EncoreCMS/test.php">
        <label>Username</label><input type="text" name="userName" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I have never used SSL before so maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Programs like Fiddler is better when trying to monitor network traffic as you will see the raw data transferred on the wire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome knows what the plaintext is, obviously, so it shows it to you. If you're using https the stuff *on the wire* is encrypted.